# Two variable products on one product page Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've looked everywhere and tried multiple plugins to achieve this like linked variants, group products, product bundles etc. and didn't think it would be this difficult. So basically I want two variable products which each have size and color variants, which are added to each already, to display on the same product page using Woocommerce. I'm using printful and have a hoodie with different sizes and colors and a t-shirt with different sizes and colors. I want to combine them both into a dropdown or allow a user to click on a radio button or thumbnail so that if they select let's say a t-shirt they can then pick the color and size next, was hoping to not have the page refresh when they pick the hoodie or tshirt. Manually, this would take ages as I'd have to add the design to each color and size individually and then sync it to an already existing product so I was wondering is there is a plugin, some sort of code to achieve this or if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you kindly in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom page with your builder where you will manually code the tabs widget with html (this could help you to build your HTML tabs - [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)) or use builder tabs widget if it supports shortcodes and then into these tabs you could add `woocommerce product shortcode` to call each product into each tab separately.

For example

TAB 1 = `[product_page id=1]` -  tshirt 
TAB 2 = `[product_page id=2]` - hoodie

User will be able switch tabs without refreshing the current page. Do not forget to change ids in the shortcodes with your product IDs.